# Is hacked together thread safety the 'best' course of action?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

I'm aware that no STL container guarantees thread safety. I also know that it's not terribly difficult to implement with std::lock_guard. However, for what i'm currently doing, I will at least one thread to push things onto a deque and another to take them off. There is no guaranteed number of threads, but I can guarantee that each thread with either push or pull, but not both, if that's at all relevant.

I've been doing something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
class SafeDeque {
    std::deque<T, Args...> m_deque;
    std::mutex m_mu;

public:
    SafeDeque() { }

    void push_back(const T& val) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mu);
        m_deque.push_back(val);
    }

    void push_front(const T& val) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mu);
        m_deque.push_front(val);
    }

    T& back(void) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mu);
        return m_deque.back();
    }

    const T& back(void) const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mu);
        return m_deque.back();
    }

    T& front(void) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mu);
        return m_deque.front();
    }

    const T& front(void) const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mu);
        return m_deque.front();
    }

};
```

However, this just 'feels' weird on some level. Is there a better way of doing it using only standard C++11/14? I've seen this:
https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue

But I'd rather stick with something standard if I can help it.

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that no other thread is going to remove an element from the queue, these `front()`s and `back()`s are not thread-safe. After they return, the lock is released, and nothing stops another thread from flushing the queue value down the drain, leaving a dangling reference for the hapless thread to deal with.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good point. It's really one thread doing each as of now, but that is something to watch for if/when I expand it. Thanks.

Comment: Although, I am using shared_ptr's as objects on here...

Answer (score 3):

What are you proposing is concurrency 101. You should look into some other libraries.

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks
2. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lockfree.html

Answer (score 2):

Better would be to use an multiple-producer, multiple-consumer queue.  Many implementations exist, e.g. https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/MPMCQueue.h or https://github.com/brycelelbach/boost.lockfree/blob/master/boost/lockfree/deque.hpp